# Aerospike error when applying module

Tags: python, aerospike

how to debug Exception: (100L, "/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/pooja.lua:5: bad argument #1 to 'append' (userdata expected, got string)", 'src/main/aerospike/as_command.c', 730) when applying a module.

Comment: please share pooja.lua

Comment: My best guess without that is that you are using a list.append() call and the first argument to that is not a list object.

Comment: function list_append(rec, bin, value)
  local l = rec[bin]
  list.append(l, value)
  rec[bin] = l
  aerospike:update(rec)
  return 0
end

Comment: @sunil Is it compulsory to install aerospike c client for aerospike python client

Comment: No need to explicitly download c client. when you install python using pip, it will download and compile it automatically.

Comment: @sunil when i am pass a key through client.apply(key,module,function,arg) lua module doesn't understand what is key and when i am return key from the lua module it gives blank space why ??

Comment: lets use different thread for different question

Comment: @sunil did you apply module using aerospike python client ??

Answer (score 1):

My best guess without seeing your lua file is that you are using a list.append() call and the first argument to that is not a list object.